# Как разделить сумму на 4 значения по весам(целыми числами) без изменения контрольной суммы результата? Гугл таблицы

Tags: excel, google-spreadsheet

Есть 4 сущности. Они имеют свои весовые коэфы, которые дают в сумме 1.
Нужно распределить число, например 12, исходя из этих весовых коэфов
НО! Полученные значения должны быть целыми. Если число на сущности <1 , то поставить 1 и сумма всех значений на сущностях после всех манипуляций должна быть также = 12.
Без проблем получается сделать это, если использовать вещественные числа, но вот с округлением проблемы, то 11 выходит, то 13, в зависимости от округления и коэфов

Comment: Очень просто: если сумма после всех манипуляций не равна 12, то находим самое большое число и меняем на 1 что бы сумма приблизилась к 12. Повторяем пока не будет 12.

Comment: При округлении весовые коэффициенты сместятся. И если коэффициенты строго заданы и смещать нельзя, то задача не имеет решения. Должна быть разрешена небольшая девиация.   Покажите пример.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UtVys58KL-_2sQNaw0mDSR8NZSOjBs8Ku92zrnQQhcM/edit#gid=0
Табличка. Весовые коэфы строятся относительно прошлой итерации. На первой итерации каждая сущность = 3

Comment: Вы не ответили - колебания весов допускаются?

Comment: Они зависят от прошлой итерации, в теории - можно.
Чем больше на прошлой итерации выполнено в %, тем больше квестов выдадут на следующей итерации

Comment: Пока непонятно, как веса (коэффициенты) зависят от предыдущих итераций. Расскажите, покажите в таблице примеры изменения весов (строк 5-10).

Comment: Берется кол-во выполненных квестов с итерации. Делятся на сумму всех квестов. Таким образом мы получаем вес. Пример.
Фракция (ф) 1 - 2 квеста
Ф2 - 1 квест
ф3 - 3 квеста
ф4 - 0 квестов
Для расчета веса 1 фракции мы делим 2 на (ф1+ф2+ф3+ф4). Получаем 0,33 (33%)

Comment: Или дробь 2/6. Остальные веса также считаются и в сумме дают 1 (100%)

Comment: Пока сделал несколько иную реализацию на листе (5 задание). Где, при выходе за 12 квестов - отнимается от макс элементов разница. 
Но с дробной частью до сих пор проблемы

Answer (score 0):

Три значения:

```
=ОКРУГЛ($J$2*коэфф;0)
```

Но с учетом того, что при малом весе значение может получиться <1, формулу для первых трех нужно усложнить:

```
=МАКС(1;ОКРУГЛВНИЗ($J$2*коэфф;0))
```

Последнее - разность общего количества и суммы трех значений

```
=J2-СУММ(B2:D2)
```